# Average of geometric mean across subsamples

Tags: sample, geometric-mean

I am looking for a simple closed-form expression simplifying the sum (or average, if you prefer) of the geometric means of all subsamples $A\subset X$ of cardinality $|A|=k$ from a grand set $X$,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{A\subset X: |A|=k}\left(\prod_{x\in A} x \right)^{1/|A|}
\end{equation*}
Is there any identity that would allow for such simplification?

EDIT: The question is motivated by the expression
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{e\in\{0,1\}^N:\sum_i e_i=k}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i e_i \right)
\end{equation*}
which I am hoping to simplify.

Comment: Of course: calculate the sum.  What are you really looking for?  An algorithm with an asymptotic time better than $O\left((\min(|X|-k,k)\,\binom{|X|}{k}\right)$? Answers will depend on the potential values of $|X|$ and $k$ you have in mind as well as whether you need to compute the sums for many $k$ (for a given $|X|$) or just one $k.$

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am wondering whether there exists an identity that would allow me simplify the sum to obtain a more "elegant" closed-form expression. Should I rather turn to Math SE with such a question?

Comment: You can factor this polynomial by separating all terms with $x_1$ from all terms without it and proceed recursively.  The $1/|A|$ power is superfluous: you might as well apply it to all the $x_i$ before even starting.  It's difficult to see any further simplifications in the generic, one-off case.  When $|A|$ is large, asymptotic approximations can be developed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did try the recursion. "It's difficult to see any further simplifications in the generic, one-off case." is exactly what I was wondering, after trying in vain to simplify further. I was just wondering whether there might be a result I am unaware of. Thanks for your help!